# Sleep current of automotive device increasing over time

Tags: heat, sleep, vibration

I have something like a tire pressure monitor. It is battery operated. I haven't done automotive before and it is a whole other world besides consumer. I put in all high temp components (i,e, 40-125C vs 40-85C). I can't really find much info on what happens to IC and components in a high temp, high mechanical stress environment. My question is: my sleep current when I install is low uA, but a few months later it cam become 1 mA without changing anything. Is there a descriptive cause of what happens? I wonder about the ceramic caps (there are no tantalum or electrolytic). Do they develop fractures causing greater leakage of current?. I don't see anything on the web about what happens. If I knew, I could justify spending more on problem components I identify.

Comment: About the ceramic capacitors, are they "automotive grade" such as Murata GCM? My understanding is that every component in the system needs to meet the automotive spec (AEC-Q200)

Comment: how clean is the device after few months use? ... could dirt be placing a load on the battery?

Comment: How do you know it is higher - why are you measuring it, are the batteries failing prematurely? The current will be higher when the sensor is active, which it will be periodically or when the accelerator detects motion.

Comment: You can easily find multiple papers explaining failure modes of MLCCs caused by micro cracking and subsequent moisture and electro migration. You should be able to perform failure analysis on the units you have. The cracking could be from manufacturing or use conditions, if that’s in fact what is happening. I don’t think it does anyone much good to copy contents of such papers here,

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The capacitors are automotive grade. The device is hermetically sealed. The device is in sleep mode, everything is off. I will look for papers.

Comment: I found an answer which is actually kind of exciting. The uC in sleep mode sets the gpios to inputs. On of the gpios was the reset for another sleeping part. When this reset would float down it would take the part out of sleep mode into standby mode, but only randomly. It was like a floating gate on the mosfet input.

Comment: @BSEE - Hi, Interesting update, thanks. Can you please write it as an answer instead of a comment, so that you can accept it, and readers can quickly see that there is now an answer? Also, your comment states the problem that you found, but have you also chosen a solution? If I understand correctly, it seems like a pull-up resistor is needed on that pin. Including your chosen solution as well (and perhaps a relevant snippet of the schematic) would make a great answer :-) Thanks!